# PDO setAttribute on a per transaction basis

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I would like to know if it is possible to set the PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE on a per transaction basis instead of a per connection basis.

I open a database connection in `class Database` and am currently setting the attribute there:

```
namespace Core {
    class Database {
        private $pdo;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->pdo = new \PDO(/*Connection arguments*/);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

        public function getConnection() {
            return $this->pdo;
        }
    }
}
```

All errors will now throw exceptions, however, I would only like this behaviour when dealing with manual transactions.

Ideally, I would be able to do something like:

```
namespace Repositories {
    class Something {
        private $pdo;

        public function __construct(\Core\Database $database) {
            $this->pdo = $database->getConnection();
        }

        public function doSomething() {
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // Set the attribute here
            $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

            try {
                // Execute some queries and statements
                $this->pdo->commit();
            }
            catch (\PDOException $e) {
                $this->pdo->rollback();
                // Do something with $e
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for the error mode to be returned to its default at the end of the method (I know my example wouldn't work)

Thanks in advance

It may be useful for you to know that I do not create a new PDO connection in each method that uses one, but the Database class is stored in an object pool when it is first created.

Comment: You can set the attribute any time you want, is that the question

Comment: No, I want to know if I can set the attribute only temporarily while I perform manual transactions.

Comment: What about something like this `$pdo = $this->pdo; 
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` this way it stays in you function scope

Comment: I see what you mean, but will assigning `$pdo` to `$this->pdo` only copy the reference instead of the actual object, and therefore still change the attribute for `$this->pdo`?

Comment: Ah I guess doing `$pdo = clone $this->pdo;` could work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$pdo = $this->pdo;  
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Would I need to clone `$this->pdo`?